# Expecting Zend to fail to find an action, but instead it finds it and tries to render a view

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

With an action such as `public function checkImagesAction()` I can request that route in my browser with `/checkImages` and the page is displayed using the `check-images.phtml` view as I'd expect.

However, requesting /checkImageS or another crazy spelling causes Zend to throw a `RuntimeException` because it is `unable to render template check-Images-S`

I'm guessing that this has to do with the use of routes of the form

```
   'route' => '/thing[/:action][/]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
```

Why does Zend match the action despite the crazy upper and lower-casing but then tries to hyphenate at uppercase letters? I would have expected it to fail, *or* to use only the hyphenated version of the matched action, which would be check-images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. By default ZF will render templates based on the action name, but it uses hyphenation for template names as a convention, and will convert camel-cased actions into this format. PHP functions are not case sensitive, so in your example, `checkImageSAction()` is what gets called, and so `check-image-s.phtml` is what ZF then tries to render.

Personally I avoid upper-case letters in URLs - just personal preference, but it would be an easy fix in your case. Alternatively you could make the route a bit more explicit:

```
'route' => '/thing/checkImages[/]',
            'constraints' => array(
                'action' => 'check-images'
            ),
```

Comment: I didn't realize php functions didn't care about upper vs lower case. Is that really true? I'm off too test this right now.

Comment: Looking around it looks like the function names aren't case sensitive. I have no idea why the design decision was to make case matter when it came to templates when it won't with actions (because of the function names), but I think this is reason.